# How do I call an async function inside jest mockImplementation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

We are working on e2e tests for our project using jest.

In the `main.spec.ts` we wrote test that executes the flow and overrides a specific async method in the general flow (using `jest.fn().mockImplementation(...)`).

The overridden method is async and I need a dynamic response data (not const, not really a mock object).

Is there a way to override the implementation of a specific method (like jest allows us to do) but still wait for the response? because now the general flow receives `undefined` when calling the overridden async method.

```
// main.spec.ts
someModule.someAsyncMethod = jest.fn().mockImplementation(async () => {...});
```

```
// someModule
import {someAsyncMethod} from '@another/module/we/want/to/override'
async executor() {
  ...
  const response = await someAsyncMethod()
  ...
}
```

When we debug the test, we see that the override is working and the overridden method is called.

Jest have a method called `mockResolvedValue`, but is there a definition for `mockResolvedFunction` perhaps? or any other workaround?

We already tried using `mockImplementation`, `mockResolvedValue`, `withImplementation` and all of them didn't work

Comment: It's hard to tell you what's wrong with code like this: `jest.fn().mockImplementation(async () => {...});` from which you apparently removed the most important part: the `{...}`